# Почему нельзя добавить foreign key ссылающийся на другой foreign key?

Tags: sql, база-данных

допустим у меня есть 3 таблицы "Товары", "Заказы", "Товары на складе"

В  "Заказы" мы можем добавить только товары из таблицы "Товары", А в "Товары на складе" только товары из "Заказы"
т.е. `GoodsID` - `primary key` таблица `Goods`
таблица Orders столбец GoodsID -`Foreign key references Goods(GoodsID)`
но в таблицу "Goods on stock" нельзя добавить `GoodsID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ORDERS(GoodsID)`, т.к. недопустимо ссылки внешнего ключа  на внешний: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ключ, только на первичный ключ. Как добавить требуемое ограничение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос, вынесенный в заголовок: нельзя, потому что внешний ключ должен ссылаться на уникальный столбец (если совсем формально, то на потенциальный ключ). Сам же внешний ключ уникальным быть не обязан (и в большинстве случаев и не может таким быть). Например, в терминах вопроса — на один и тот же товар может быть сделано несколько заказов.

Ответ на вопрос, содержащийся в тексте: судя по фразе `«В "Заказы" мы можем добавить только товары из таблицы "Товары", А в "Товары на складе" только товары из "Заказы"»`, в таблице `Goods on stock` Вам нужна ссылка отнюдь не на `Orders(GoodsID)`, а на `Orders(OrdersID)`.

Comment: Тогда получается 1 и то же товар может быть внесен в таблицу "товары на складе" несколько раз

Comment: Значит, внешний ключ в таблице `Товары на складе` должен ссылаться на таблицу `Товары` (что, в общем-то, логично). Ну и дополнительно сделать проверку (`CHECK CONSTRAINT`) на наличие товара в заказах.